# Is there a way to block while waiting for a websocket response in the browser?

Tags: javascript

Perhaps by (mis)using some legacy API?
Are there browser plugins that can do this?

*I am in a controlled environment, so solutions involving browser plugins or browser modifications are welcome.*

**Background:**
I have some JS running in an embedded JavaScript VM, using custom methods exposed from C++. These custom methods are synchronous (there is no need for them to be asynchronous).

For testing and development, I want to be able to run the same JS code in the browser. As the browser does not have my custom C++ methods, I need to call them remotely.
Today, I'm using a blocking XMLHttpRequest (deprecated in most browsers, but still works) to do this.

The problem is that making an HTTP-request has some overhead and is relatively slow (in the 20-50 ms range). WebSockets are much faster (roundtrip in a few ms), but as they are inherently asynchronous, I can't use it to replace my blocking functions.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to have a blocking/synchronous request?  Couldn't you just put like an overlay over the page (that says "loading"), that blocks the user from doing anything until the asynchronous request is done.

Comment: I do not know any method to make a websocket inherently synchronous. Therefore, I would try to put a lightweight envelope around each message having a message_id. The javascript application would then not accept any other websocket events until the request-response cycle for a given message_id has been completed. The resulting behaviour is similar to a synchronous socket.

Comment: For the reasons I mentioned in the question, the call *needs* to be synchronous